# Which folder to put the App and Scene Delegate files in Swift?

Tags: swift, appdelegate, uiscenedelegate

I am having a problem to decide on which folder to put the app and delegate in.

My project structure is like this.
[image]

Should I create a folder for each of them with their names or create a folder called "Supporting files" ? Can someone give me an advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually keep them in my root folder as the rest of the app goes into their own folders.

This is a question of preference I believe that there is no wrong answer here as long as the code inside the files is correct.